# iOS: NSPredicate for Custom object as attribute

Tags: objective-c, ios, nspredicate

For an NSObject class A that contains another NSObject class B variable as member, can we make use of NSPredicate to perform a search on an array containing objects of class A by using that member?

Thanks
Arnieterm

Comment: Just need to check whether the member is nil or non nil

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to filter an existing array of objects of type A where their B member attribute, let's call it objectB, matches a particular value? So, first the predicate:

```
NSPredicate *predicate =
  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"objectB == %@", aBInstance ];
```

And then just filter your source array using the predicate:

```
NSArray *filtered  = [yourSourceArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```